# примитивный барьер для многопоточности

Tags: c++, многопоточность

здравствуйте, вот, допустим, вызываем основной поток, делаем что-то, далее запускаем несколько других потоков, которые должны исполняться строго асинхронно(притом каждый из них разное время исполняется), приостанавливаем основной, а после завершения каждого из вызываемых потоков продолжаем выполнять основной. подходит ли следующий код для такой стратегии, или есть более красивые решения:

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

int main() {
    //идет основной поток
    //...
    std::condition_variable var;
    std::mutex m;
    //пусть будут три потока с разной длительностью
    std::atomic<bool> a1(false);
    std::atomic<bool> a2(false);
    std::atomic<bool> a3(false);
    std::thread([&]{ std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(3000)); a1 = true; var.notify_one();}).detach();
    std::thread([&]{ std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(7000)); a2 = true; var.notify_one();}).detach();
    std::thread([&]{ std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500)); a3 = true; var.notify_one();}).detach();

    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(m);
        while(!(a1 && a2 && a3))
            var.wait(locker);
    }
    //...
    // продолжаем основной поток
```

з.ы. в общем можно было просто все потоки джоинить и все, я чет сразу не допер. к тому же даже ожидание криво реализовано, надо было так:

```
{
     std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(m);
     var.wait(locker, [&]{ return (a1 && a2 && a3);});
}
```

Comment: Вроде ж для cond.var нужно отправлять нотификацию под мьютексом? Заодно и не понадобится `std::atomic`.

Comment: не понял вас... атомики защищают от ложного пробуждения

Comment: Хм, а каким образом защищают? Можно ссылку про это почитать?

Comment: ну не сами атомики, а условие в цикле, как тут, например, https://habrahabr.ru/post/182626/
другое дело, что достаточно, по идее и обычного булевского типа, однако вдруг там процессор переставит переменные и т.д., короче атомики имхо надежнее

Comment: А вот должно быть не «а вдруг», а надо точно знать, какая конструкция что гарантирует. Вот блокировка мьютекса в пишущем потоке гарантирует, например, отсутствие всяческих «перестановок». И необходимость использовать медленный `atomic` [отпадает](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8OIPOZdbVXs).

Comment: мьютекс реально гарантирует отсутствие процессорных оптимизаций?

Comment: Почему бы не использовать join()?

Comment: асинхронно должны работать потоки ж

Comment: @xperious, Так они и будут работать асинхронно, а главный поток будет их всех ждать.

Comment: @xperious: Мьютекс гарантирует, что через границы lock/unlock не распространяется отложенное чтение/запись переменных, а также в этих точках выставляется memory barrier.

Comment: @Pavel Parshin, если делаем join(), то выполняется один, затем другой, затем третий, а надо чтобы они гарантированно параллельно выполнялись

Comment: @VladD, ясно, но в этом я не шарю

Comment: @xperious Последняя попытка, может я что-то не понимаю... http://ideone.com/xapm6B

Comment: @Pavel Parshin, хм, попробуйте случай который я описал в примере выше...

Comment: @Pavel Parshin, попробовал, вы правы...

Comment: @xperious Вот и отлично) оформил в виде ответа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно использовать функцию `join` для ожидания выполнения потоков. [Рабочий пример](http://ideone.com/xapm6B):

```
void f(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Message from thread #" << n << ": iteration #" << i << "\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
    }
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Main thread: build threads pool\n";
    std::vector<std::thread> pool;
    pool.push_back(std::thread{f, 1});
    pool.push_back(std::thread{f, 2});
    pool.push_back(std::thread{f, 3});
    std::for_each(pool.begin(), pool.end(), std::mem_fn(&std::thread::join));
    std::cout << "Main thread: all threads finished.\n";
}
```